# Failed to retrieve list of IAM roles and policies. (Loading Roles Error)

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I am receiving this error message when trying to upload to an AWS Lambda.  This is from the [AWS Example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-visual-studio/latest/user-guide/lambda-rekognition-example.html)  - example

In particular it says IAM is not authorized to perform iam:ListRoles nor iam:ListPolicies.

I checked my IAM user's AWS Lambda ListFunctions in the AWS policy simulator which says it is working , although I do not know if this is relevant to my problem.

- thanks
  [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eU8Kj.png)
  [Policy Simulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UZ2fL.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your IAM user which is being used here might not be having permissions to perform operations like `iam:ListRoles`. Please try out the following steps:

1. Go to your AWS Console. And select the IAM service.
2. Then choose the `Users` tab on the left hand side.
3. Select the particular user(it's named `General` I guess).
4. In the permissions tab, click on `Add Permissions`
5. A new view should be present where you need to select `Attach existing policies directly` option on the top.
6. Select the option `Create Policy`.
7. Now create a new policy by selecting service as `IAM`, and Actions as required(`List` actions) and select `All resources`, and create the policy.
8. Then select this newly created policy in the step 5 view and add permissions.
9. Now retry with the uploading of Lambda.

Comment: Thanks!  I was not completing item 8 properly.

Comment: `iam:ListRoles` was the permission missing